# in NEXTJS Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using nextjs and mui. I am facing a warning when rendering pages. Here is my code. Please help to solve the issue!!!

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import useGetAuthentication from "../hooks/useGetAuthentication";
import States from "../interfaces/states";
import STATUS from "../constants/status";
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "../styles/theme";
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";
import * as React from "react";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}

const checkStatusCode = (statusCode: number): boolean => {
  return statusCode === STATUS.NOT_FOUND || statusCode === STATUS.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
};

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { states } = pageProps;
  const { statusCode } = pageProps;
  const { isAuthorized } = useGetAuthentication(states as States);

  console.log("App -> Component", Component);
  console.log("App -> pageProps", pageProps);
  console.log("App -> states", states);
  console.log("App -> statusCode", statusCode);
  const drawerWidth: number = 240;
  if (!checkStatusCode(statusCode) && !isAuthorized)
    return (
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          p: 3,
          width: { lg: "230px", sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` }
        }}
      >
        <Login />
      </Box>
    );

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login component is below**

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import authenticationStore from "../../stores/persistences/authenticationStore";
import TestHttp from "../../httpModules/testHttp";
import STATUS from "../../constants/status";
import RequestSignIn from "../../interfaces/test/requestSignIn";
import styles from "./login.module.scss";
import { Alert, FormControlLabel, Grid, Paper, TextField, Typography, Stack, Button, Checkbox } from "@mui/material";
import Image from "next/image";
import useLoginInputs from "../../hooks/useLoginInputs";
import LocalStorageHandler from "../../utils/localStorageHandler";
import RememberId from "../../interfaces/rememberId";
import ERROR_MESSAGE from "../../constants/errorMessage";
import LOGIN_INFO from "../../constants/loginInfo";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const localStorageHandler = new LocalStorageHandler<RememberId>();
  const authorize = authenticationStore((state) => state.authorize);
  const testHttp = new TestHttp();
  const { inputs, setInputs, isRememberChecked, isError, setIsError, isIdEmpty, setIsIdEmpty, isPasswordEmpty, setIsPasswordEmpty, inputsHandler, checkboxHandler } = useLoginInputs([
    "id",
    "password"
  ]);

  const { id, password } = inputs;

  const onLoginHandler = async (): Promise<void> => {
    if (isIdEmpty) {
      return setIsError(ERROR_MESSAGE.ID_EMPTY);
    }
    if (isPasswordEmpty) {
      return setIsError(ERROR_MESSAGE.PASSWORD_EMPTY);
    }
    const signInInfo: RequestSignIn = { id, password };
    const { statusCode, jsonResult } = await testHttp.signIn(false, signInInfo);

    /*
     *   인증 실패 (아이디, 비밀번호 일치 하지 않는 경우 등) 발생 시 코드 작성
     */

    if (statusCode !== STATUS.OK) {
      setIsError(true);
      return;
    }
    const { userInfo, tokenInfo } = jsonResult;
    authorize(statusCode, userInfo, tokenInfo);
    if (!isRememberChecked) return localStorageHandler.removeLocalStorageData(LOGIN_INFO.REMEMBER_ID);
    localStorageHandler.setLocalStorageData("rememberId", {
      id
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("하이");
    setIsIdEmpty(id.length <= 0);
    setIsPasswordEmpty(password.length <= 0);
    setIsError(null);
  }, [id, password]);

  console.log("id", id);
  console.log("password", password);
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Paper elevation={10} className={styles.container}>
        <Grid align={"center"}>
          <div className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src={"/images/logo.svg"} width={"200px"} height={"80px"} alt={"logo"} />
            <Typography variant={"h6"}>관리자</Typography>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Stack spacing={1} justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"} className={styles["login-container"]}>
          <TextField name={"id"} placeholder={"아이디를 입력해주세요."} required value={id} type={"text"} className={styles["login-input"]} onChange={inputsHandler} />
          <TextField name={"password"} placeholder={"비밀번호를 입력하세요."} required value={password} type={"password"} className={styles["login-input"]} onChange={inputsHandler} />
        </Stack>
        <Stack>
          <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={isRememberChecked} />} label={"아이디 저장"} className={styles.checkbox} onChange={checkboxHandler} />
        </Stack>
        <Stack justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
          <Button type={"submit"} color={"primary"} variant={"contained"} className={styles["login-button"]} size={"large"} onClick={onLoginHandler}>
            로그인
          </Button>
        </Stack>
        <Stack justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"} className={styles["error-message"]}>
          <div>
            {isError && (
              <Alert severity={"error"}>
                <strong>{isError}</strong>
              </Alert>
            )}
          </div>
        </Stack>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**the warning is**

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:36:72)
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./layouts/Layout/index.tsx:16:26)
    at InnerThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:21:70)
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/private-theming/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:47:5)
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:41:5)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:61:27)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:20638)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:23179)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:323:9)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:820:26)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:944:27)
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:25
```

Comment: Doe`s it happen when moving to a specific page or general?

Comment: You have to setup Material UI for SSR in `_app` and `_document` as in the official example: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/HEAD/examples/nextjs-with-typescript.

Comment: Updated example link: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/HEAD/examples/material-ui-nextjs-ts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In progress value update from use hook can also causing this problem. To prevent it, just copy the variable value from hook to state from useEffect hook. Here is the example

```
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";

...

  const { address, isConnected, isConnecting } = useAccount();
  // the value of these variable above are changed dynamically
  
  const [connectionStat, setConnectionStat] = useState();
  const [addr, setAddr] = useState();

  // copy the value to state here
  useEffect(() => {
    setConnectionStat(isConnected);
    setAddr(address);
  }, [address, isConnected])

  // then now we can display the value properly

  return (
    <div>
     <p>Connection status :  {connectionStat}</p>
     <p>Connected to      :  {addr}</p>
      ....
    </div>
  );
```

Explanation: passing value directly from hook to JSX/view may causing inconsistent value inside JSX/view so the the page render can not be consistent as well and there will be different value between value in SSR and client.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

## Case 1

Most likely a `Server<>Client` out of date issue.

#### Fix

- If you are using the development server > Restart it.
- If you are getting this production > Rebuild + Restart.

## Case 2

The components you are using render differently (due to bad coding) on the Server (SSR) vs Client (CSR). This can be silenced by adding `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` to the offending component.

## Case 3

Another case I've seen is that someone has set `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` with invalid HTML. The fix is to correct the HTML OR silence it as we did in case 2.

Comment: Was case 3 for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me! Case 3 solved my problem. It turned out to be an unclosed tag in the WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Willywes how to solved the unclosed tag issue in WYSIWYG?

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar by closing it.  If you have an <img> tag make sure to either close with </img> or self-close with <img />

Comment: I don't want to downvote this but Case One doesn't address the problem and Case 2 is downright dangerous.  Rebuild since "(due to bad coding)" is the problem.  Case 3 is a lovely response though!

Answer (score 8):

The genuine issue I had was that LastPass extension was injecting the bloody DIV element into my code. Something like this:

```
<div data-lastpass-icon-root="true" style="position: relative !important; height: 0px !important; width: 0px !important; float: left !important;"></div>
```

That obviously caused server and client to have a different node structure. Once exempted localhost from LastPass (which wasn't easy!) the error disappeared.

Comment: To exempt localhost from LastPass you can add it as a "Never URL" following [these instructions](https://support.lastpass.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=lastpass&topicId=LastPass/Manage_Never_URLs.html&_LANG=enus) and add `localhost/*` as the URL.

Comment: @bluepanda Tried all of those but did not work for me. With any type of regex. Perhaps someone will have more luck.

Comment: You may have luck trying the others mentioned here? https://www.reddit.com/r/Lastpass/comments/xde8wh/comment/ixytf25/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error and it turns out I had a react component outside the body tag in one of my jsx files, specifically layout.tsx.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I tried to run localStorage getItem method outside useEffect hook.
So probably you can place your async code inside that hook.

Comment: Hi, i also got this error since the moment i set up usage of localStorage, how did you fix it exactly?

Comment: I placed my LS read and write operations inside useEffect hook as I can remember

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and resolved it by refreshing the browser

- Clear Cache
- Clear Cooke
- or Try a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was rendering some elements depending on the user token if it exists or not and I saved the token in localStorag so when I open local storage in the browser, I found the token exists and it was for another project using the same localhost with the same port, and the browser was assuming that the token is related to the current opened project, so I just cleared the localStorage in browser and everything works well

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using useSelector and in the next line I was just iterating the elements from the selector and directly appending them into the array. Then I used useEffect hook and then error goes away. Thanks to azwar_akbar for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was about the state and it's update. I was depending on a browser's Operation System and i was rendering it conditionally. Whenever i use usestate and useEffect, the warning and error have gone.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a series of challenging errors in my Next.js 14 application. The application was throwing these errors:

1. `Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <a> in <div>.`
2. `Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`
3. `Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.`

At first, I wasn't sure where the problem was, so I started commenting out each component until I narrowed it down to the navigation component. Here is the original Navbar component that was causing the issue:

```
// Original Navbar Component
import Link from "next/link";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
      {/* Content including <Link> components */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And this is the RootLayout component where Navbar was being used:

```
// RootLayout Component
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

To my surprise, the fix turned out to be quite straightforward. I replaced the Navbar component's parent `<div>` tag with a `<nav>` tag, and all the three errors disappeared.

**Takeaway**

**Semantic HTML Matters:** Using the correct HTML element for the right purpose is good for accessibility, SEO and essential for the internal workings of frameworks like React.

I hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used a typography in mui version `^5.14.11` and next version `13.4.19` like so:

```
<Typography variant={'body2'} mt={'20px'} key={name}>
            <Chip label="mychip" />
          </Typography>
```

and got an  `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <p>`

adding `component='div'` solved my problem:

```
<Typography component='div' variant={'body2'} mt={'20px'} key={name}>
  <Chip label="mychip" />
</Typography>
```