# Next.js - SSR - Hydration fails when using Links

Tags: next.js, hyperlink, server-side-rendering

I'm encountering a hydration-error when using the Link component in a Next.js application. The error message indicates that the initial UI rendered on the client does not match the HTML generated on the server.

I found out that this issue might be related to the Link component. I'm using the latest version of Next.js (i think 13) and the app folder structure.

I'm unsure if it's even possible to use dynamic hrefs with the Link component:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-dir-dynamic-href

This is the error i get in the browser:

*Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching a tag in div.*

**When i remove the link the error goes away :)**

**But changing to an a-tag instead or using a static href, a string did not help!**

What is the problem with this link? :)

```
const Page = async () => {
  const blogs = await fetchBlog();

  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-1/3 min-h-screen mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-black mt-5">My Writings:</h1>
      <div className="mt-5 p-6 flex text-black justify-center">
      <div className="">
      <div>
        {blogs.map((blog) => (
          <div key={blog.id}>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <Image
                src={blog.acf.image.url}
                alt={blog.acf.image.alt}
                width={300}
                height={300}
                style={{ maxWidth: "300px", maxHeight: "300px" }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="font-bold mt-2">{blog.acf.title}</div>
            <div className="mb-5">
              {blog.acf.description.length > 300
                ? <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blog.acf.description.substring(0, 200) }} /> 
                : <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blog.acf.description }} />}
                <div>
                <Link className="font-bold text-black" href={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>Read More...</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nothing problem with this link, It's fine. Just I'm seeing that my eyes are full of div.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in NEXTJS Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791251/in-nextjs-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-div)

Comment: This comment helped me Azad, thx. I changed from dangerouslySetInnerHTML to HTMLReactParser and changed the divs a little bit - the error is gone :)